# Can loop devices be automatically cleaned up when a process exits?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, loop-device

I'm trying to figure out a clean and safe way to use loop devices inside of a build script.  To the best of my knowledge loop devices are required if you want to (GPT) partition and (FAT32, EXT3) format a **[sparse](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/sparse_file)** file<sup>1</sup>.

Eg: Let's say I have this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
truncate --size 4G target.img
sfdisk target.img < partitions
loop_device=$(losetup -f --show target.img)
trap "losetup -d $loop_device" EXIT
partx -u $(loop_device)
mkfs.vfat ${loop_device}p1
mkfs.ext4 ${loop_device}p2
```

In most happy and unhappy paths, the loop device will be cleaned up by bash calling `losetup`.  But there are some unhappy paths<sup>2</sup> that result in the loop device being left behind.

If this were a question about mounts, then the simple solution would be to run in a mount namespace with `unshare -m`.  That would result in the kernel cleaning up the mount point when the process exits, without the process explicitly performing the same action.

Further, if the loop device was created with a mount in the first place with `mount -o loop` then the loop device would be cleaned up when the mount point was, and so by proxy a mount namespace could also be used to clean up the loop device.

But since what I'm after is a GPT partition table on a file that's all zeros, no file system would successfully mount on it (AFAIK).

So is there some other way to get the kernel to clean up a loop device when a process, process group, namespace, ... is cleaned up?

---

- <sup>1</sup> *I'm aware that solutions exist such as formatting a separate file and then using `dd` to copy with an offset, but that results in multiple GB of zeros being written to disk instead of remaining as a sparse file.  So here the word "sparse" is very important*
- <sup>2</sup> *One obvious one is what happens when bash is killed with `kill -9`*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`losetup -d` disassociates a loop device lazily, so it can be used to remove a loop device as soon as it is no longer used. Instead of trapping, open a file descriptor to the loop device and disassociate it straight away:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
truncate --size 4G target.img
sfdisk target.img < partitions
loop_device=$(losetup -f --show target.img)
exec 5< "$loop_device"
losetup -d "$loop_device"
partx -u "$loop_device"
mkfs.vfat "${loop_device}p1"
mkfs.ext4 "${loop_device}p2"
```

When the script exits, for whatever reason, except in the short window between `losetup -f` and `losetup -d`, the loop device will be cleaned up.

Comment: That is a very short window indeed and in the absence of an atomic system call that creates a disassociated loop and returns an FD to it, I think it's as close as I'm going to get. Thanks!